# Datagrid not refreshing

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

Hi I have a datagrid that is populated via an ICollectionView

```
public ICollectionView MemberView { get; private set; }

Members = new ObservableCollection<Member>(_memberService.LoadCustomers());
MemberView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Members);
```

All works fine until I update a status on a member to 'Live' from another viewmodel.
I then try and search on this recordset but the record never turns up until I restart the application.
I am using MVVMLight and the messenger to trigger the reload (Not really important here as the messagebox confirms its running correctly)

```
private void NotificationMessageReceived(NotificationMessage msg)
    {
        if (msg.Notification == "ReloadClients")
        {
            Members = _memberService.LoadCustomers();
            MemberView.Refresh();                
            RunFilter();
            MessageBox.Show("Clients Reloaded");
        }
    }
```

Am I going about this the correct way? Any help will be very much appreciated.
Thanks Scott

Comment: Did you implement INotifyProperty changed? Or extend the ViewModelBase from mvvm light?

Comment: public class MemberMainViewModel : ViewModelBase

Comment: sorry. Yes implement mvvmlight as normal.

Comment: Ok, and you have the OnPropertyChanged in the setters? Another thing, set mode = two way. I'm not a total mvvm expert - but these are the first things I would try. I can give you a more concrete example if you need it.

Comment: I have RaisePropertyChanged("Members") on the observablecollection. Not on the IcollectionView. Just tried with , UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged but no difference. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I meant two way binding like this : <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Members, Mode=TwoWay}"

Comment: you know i am binding using the icollectionview. i wonder if that is the problem. ItemsSource="{Binding MemberView}"

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41355/discussion-between-mike-schwartz-and-scottsanpedro)

Comment: Anyone gets this. Simple solution. I was updating a property not add/remove record therefore amending the observablecollection directly with the changed fixed it.